# Firemonkey Mobile Application and remote MySQL

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe5, dbexpress, firedac

I am using Delphi XE5 and I have created basic Firemonkey Mobile Application - Delphi

I would like to connect to a remote MySQL database. Which if any database conduit do I use? (FireDAC, DBExpress, etc)?

Comment: Which version of Delphi? Enterprise? Architect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard TSQLQueries, but as your mobile app needs to connect to a remote database, you will need to go via a DataSnap service (most probably hosted on an IIS server).  The mobile device then connects to the DataSnap server which then connects to the database.

The DataSnap functions can return TDataSets which your app can then use.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Devart DAC](http://blog.devart.com/how-to-develop-ios-applications-in-delphi-xe4-using-devart-data-access-components.html)

Comment: Thanks, JackD answered the question for me : FireDAC has no support for connection to remote MySQL server

Answer (score 0):

I'm using DBExpress since XE2, it works good, but i think now FireDAC is much bettter

Comment: FireDAC has no support for connection to remote MySQL server from iOS and Android, while MyDAC and UniDAC from Devart can do this.