# Firedac does not connect on my phone but does on my computer - Delphi Xe5 - Mysql

Tags: android, mysql, delphi

I am developing a firemonkey application and testing it on my samsung S4. I have a remote mysql database that i am attempting to connect to using firedac.

Obviously this requires libmysql.dll and ive added it on the computer, and the database does connect in design mode. but when i compile and run it on my s4, it does not compile. i get the `[FireDAC][Phys]-300. Driver[MySQL] is not registered, you can drop component [tfdphmysqldriverlink into your project`

Can anybody help me resolve this?

Just to be clear as well on this. I am in need of a freeware client, Such as zeoslib etc.

Comment: I know less than zero about developing for Android personally, but you might want to take a look at this SO q, the answers and JackD's comment:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357823/firemonkey-mobile-application-and-remote-mysql in particular.  I've no idea whether it is accurate.

Comment: @martynA This does not really answer my question. as he says to use datasnap but there is no physical solution to the problem. I am very new to android development. This is my first app. So if you could talk to me like a noob and give info that would be great.

Comment: I don't know any more than you about FireDAC on Android. For FD to be able to work with mySQl on Windows. it needs libmysql.dll to access the db on the local machine or a networked one. From the Android environment, there  needs to be something running on the S4 that is the equivalent of libmysql.dll and FD on the S4 needs to know how to interact with it to access a db elsewhere.  I don't know whether an Android equiv to libmysql.dll exists, seems unlikely, nor whether FD could talk to it even if it did. [cont]

Comment: [cont] I think that's why someone suggested datasnap, because the server (on a Windows machine) can talk to a client (on S4, iPhone, etc) over network sockets.

Answer (score 0):

I use Devart MyDAC components for my firemonkey apps. It works on Android without the need for MySQL client lib.

Comment: Do you know of a free equivalent to that software?
I know for computers i usually use zeoslib but it seems they dont support android development

Answer (score 0):

This sounds obvious but did you add a tfdphmysqldriverlink component to your project?

Edit: sorry answered too quickly, looks like MySQL is not supported for android in XE5.

Like mentioned above, some options are:

1. MyDAC see http://blog.devart.com/android-database-application-development-in-rad-studio-xe5.html
2. DataSnap

Comment: To what do i link it? Because as i understand libmysql.dll is not available on the android devices

Answer (score 0):

I had same problems. And I solved as like below. It's not difficult.

1st, You need to check libmysql.dll is in the right directory. Be sure to see what you have 32bit.dll and 64bit.dll. If you don't know then you can get it from here MySQL download page both 32bit, 64bit When you compile 32-bit mode you need 32bit.dll, when 64-bit mode needs 64bit.dll

Copy it to c:/Program Files(x86)/Embarcadero/Studio/17.0/bin

Caution: when you compile 64-bit mode with 32-bit.dll it will show an error.

As you see below I use 32bit mysql.dll and MariaDB server. Quite an adventure to me but I got success. Mysql server also good.

[image: db setting information]

2nd, 
In the form, FDConeection, FDQuery, BindsourceDB
With FDconnection(double click it) you can test connection to DB.(Easy to use)
With FDQuery access DB table data from DB.
If you do well copy correct version to bin directory It has to show success message.
With BindsourceDB you can set data to listview or dbgrid some component can list up your data. 
 My case I use livebinding.

[image: Form screen]

Reference:
Here my stackoverflow.com question and answer. Please Be helpful to you. Have a nice day. Cheer up~
[cannot load vendor library libmysql.dll or libmysqld.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37834804/cannot-load-vendor-library-libmysql-dll-or-libmysqld-dll/37835239#37835239)